# BroadcastReceiver not getting updated from ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED

Tags: android, kotlin, android-broadcastreceiver, android-intentservice

I've created custom broadcast receiver to listen for battery changes (I would like to monitor the percentage level of the battery)

However I'm not getting any updates. Here is my setup:

```
class MyService : IntentService("MyService") {

val receiver: PowerConnectionReceiver = PowerConnectionReceiver()

override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
  Timber.d("Service started now")
}

override fun onCreate() {
 val batteryStatus: Intent? = 
 IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED).let { ifilter ->
  registerReceiver(receiver, ifilter)
 }

}

class PowerConnectionReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
     val status: Int = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1)
    Timber.d("Battery changed")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is this an `IntentService`? Try logging `onDestroy()`, I'm pretty sure it gets called immediately. You should be using normal Service.

Comment: You're right probably it is JobIntentService..... But they say on Oreo should use JobIntentService?

Answer (score 3):

You will receive updates for the < 1 millisecond time that your `IntentService` is running. Your `IntentService` shuts down as soon as `onHandleIntent()` returns. `IntentService` is designed for short-term transactional sorts of work, not long-term operation.

Switch to a regular `Service`. Make sure that it is a foreground service (using `startForeground()`), as otherwise it will only run for 1 minute on Android 8.0+.

Comment: But they say better use background service (JobIntentService + JobScheduler) compared to ForegroundService (with annoying notif) for sake of battery wise consumption? Some more if not mistaken JobScheduler can aware of battery changes. So which way "in this case" is better / recommended?